# Laravel Restrict Register Users

Tags: php, laravel

I currently have a very basic laravel app set up. I have simply started a laravel project with the auth extensions enables. I want to restrict users the ability to be able to register, as I only want admins to be able to register users.
Does anyone have an example of this, where only an admin can register a new user? I already of roles set up.
Thanks!

Comment: In your register controller, simply add whatever you use for an authorization check for roles.  There's a few ways to do that.  Check out the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization

Comment: You might want to have a look at laracast's laravel from scratch series.  He does a good chunk on authorization which clears up what can get a little confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to restrict `register` you can do the following method on `route` :

Change :

```
Auth::routes();
```

To,

```
Auth::routes(['register' => false]);
```